# Show or disprove: $ \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{A_n} = \overline{ \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n} $

Tags: general-topology

Show or disprove: Let X be a topological space. Let $A_n \subset X$ be for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then holds:

$  \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{A_n} = \overline{ \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n} $.

I think that the statement is wrong, because one would certainly find a set A_n, which would be united open and thereby the equality would be lost.

I have found a possible A_n in another forum:
Consider $A_n=[-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]$. The union $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n=(-1,1)$ is not closed.

But I do not know if I imagine it correctly or if it works.

What do you think of it, does my idea make sense?

Comment: Your idea makes sense.

Comment: Another counterexample is $A_n = \{ 1/n \}$.

Comment: What is $X$? What space are we talking about?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron the closure of the union will depend on what $X$ is. For example if $A_n = [-1+\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$, the answer will be different if $X=(-1,1)$ as compared to if $X=[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that equality fails, let $A_n = \left(-1+\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)$. Then, it is clear that$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{A_n} = (-1, 1)$$
and $$\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty {A_n}} = [-1, 1]$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community What? It's an explicit answer using the posters own notation. It couldn't possibly be more clear. Stupid bot.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Love the way you scolded the bot as if it was a misbehaving pet .

Comment: @clementine1001 . Just a small nitpick. For a complete answer you should also include that the statement can also be true. See my answer.

Comment: The closure depends on the ambient space $X$, so you should specify that. (What if $X = (-1,1)$, for example?)

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic statement in topology that union of infinite number of closed sets might not be closed.

There are many many counter examples. Take $X$ to be $\Bbb{R}$ with usual topology.

Take $A_{n}=[\frac{1}{n},1]$ .

Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bar{A_{n}}=(0,1]$ which is not closed.

Whereas $\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}}$ is always closed. In this case it is $[0,1]$.

However equality can hold .

For example if $X$ be any space with discrete topology then the statement is always true.

Answer (score 1):

The set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ is a counter-example, as each element is closed, but the closure of the union is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Not if $X=\mathbb{Q}$. You have to specify the ambient space.